# How to add filter for div elements by class/id for dom-to-image library?

Tags: dom-to-image

can someone help me ?

i will use dom-to-image library, but i can't write filter for div classes or div id's.
I tried to google, but I didn't learn anything more about filtering.
here is my code.  :

```
function filter (node) {
    return (node.tagName !== 'i');
}

domtoimage.toSvg(document.getElementById('container'), {filter: filter})
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
    /* do something */
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace with this. it might help others too.

```
function filter(node) {
   if (node.classList) return !node.classList.contains("PopOverWrap");
   return true;
}
```